# How recover cassandra datacenter after failure

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have the following datacenter-aware configuration:

1. Primary Datacenter: 3 node cluster, RF=3
2. Secondary Datacenter: 3 node cluster, RF=33
3. Data size is more than 100GB per node

Assuming that secondary datacenter is breakdown. Recovered after failure after few days.

How I can sync data from primary datacenter to secondary quickly?

I tried "nodetool repair" with various keys. But it takes much time.

Answer (score 1):

Nodetool rebuild will be faster in this case. It is just streams all the data from the other DC.